# How to check foreman collecting facts from all hosts

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, theforeman

Want to write automation script to ensure foreman collecting facts from all nodes

How to ensure foreman having facts from all nodes ?

Answer (score 1):

A fact is a key/value data pair that represents some aspect of node state, such as its IP address, uptime, operating system, or whether it's a virtual machine.

**1. Manual process are:**

a. Login to foreman UI, click Monitor->Facts

b. run `facter -p` on hosts

**2. Automation:**
   I have written below script to check facts from each hosts

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import json

foreman_url = "https://foreman_ip/api/hosts"
username = "admin"
password = "changeme"
node = "node1.puppet.com"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}    
def retrive_hostid():
  host_id = requests.get(foreman_url, headers=headers, verify=False, auth=(username, password))
  hostobj = json.loads(host_id.content)
  for s in hostobj:
     print s['host']['name']
     host_name = s['host']['name']
     url = foreman_url  + host_name + '/facts'  # check facts from each hosts
     print url
     response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False, auth=('admin', 'changeme'))
     #print response
     respobj = json.loads(response.content)
     print respobj['total'] # display total number of facts found

retrive_hostid()
```